# Why do some tag-style vote number indicators lack padding?

Tags: bug, design

The first one looks weird compared to the second:

[image: screenshot]

Not sure if this affects all sites or just SO, so I didn't post on Meta.SE.

Comment: @Rizier123 Can you please tell me what's the point of image-link that links to the same image?

Comment: The image didn't show up first (somehow it does now in the revision), so I used the image button to put the image in the question.

Comment: @Rizier123 I can see it allright, and the revision looks real weird: [image description](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcvkd.png) I'll remove the link as I find it confusing.